# MATLAB Warning - Davies-Bouldin Failing to Converge

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm currently trying to run the Davies-Bouldin Evaluation on a dataset using the inbuilt function on the R2014a version of MATLAB. When running the function on larger sample of the data, I keep receiving Warnings similar to the following:

```
"Warning: Failed to converge in 100 iterations during replicate 5. 
> In kmeans>loopBody at 397
  In smartForReduce at 128
  In kmeans at 299
  In ClusterCriterion>@(X,NC)(kmeans(X,NC,'EmptyAction','singleton','rep',5)) at 466
  In ClusterCriterion>ClusterCriterion.evalFun at 309
  In DaviesBouldinEvaluation>DaviesBouldinEvaluation.evalklist at 105
  In DaviesBouldinEvaluation>DaviesBouldinEvaluation.DaviesBouldinEvaluation at 81
  In evalclusters at 176"
```

I think I understand where this is coming from and my guess is I need to increase the maximum number of iterations to eliminate this, and to subsequently get a better answer.

My question is, is there a parameter I can change to increase the maximum number of iterations? I know you can do this for the k-means routine in MATLAB but unfortunately  can't find anything on the Davies-Bouldin index.

Thanks a lot,

Iga

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying a string as the [clustering algorithm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/evalclusters.html#inputarg_clust), you can pass a function handle. That way you tell the [`kmeans`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html) algorithm the max number of iterations (100 by default). Example:

```
% clustering algorithm
clustFcn = @(X,K) kmeans(X, K, ...
    'EmptyAction','singleton', 'Replicates',5, ...
    'Options',statset('MaxIter',100));

load fisheriris
eva = evalclusters(meas, clustFcn, 'DaviesBouldin', 'KList',2:6)
```